# How to modify the handling of a SIP message in Freeswitch?

Tags: freeswitch, sofia-sip

I need to do special handling in `freeswitch` when receiving a `REFER` message from an `Avaya SIP` trunk. But I am not sure whether `Sofia-SIP` allows users to specify a callback hook when `REFER` is received. I haven't found one.

I want to add a custom `freeswitch` module just to handle `REFER`. How can I force `Sofia-SIP` to cede control to my custom module while handling `REFER`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having FreeSWITCH, i would recommend using the LUA module that provides a Event Callback for the REFER handling. This can allow you control with what you want to do with the REFER message.

mod_lua is well documented as a module in freeswitch. The pain is coding in LUA which is easy or hard based on your preferences.

Comment: Ah! I looked up whether an event is generated when out-of-dialogue REFER is received. It does generate CALL_SETUP_REQ event, which I can easily catch in my custom module written in C++. I don't need lua to process it. Thanks, this works for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to place Kamailio server between them, and do the granular message handling as required

Comment: Hmm.. I just have a 20 line c++ code that needs to be executed when REFER is received by freeswitch. Does Kamailio let me execute my code? BTW, I don't want to run into GPL license issues.

Comment: You can easily rewrite this piece in kamailio script language. I don't know how easy it is to add a c++ code to kamailio, need to look up the docs.

Comment: Let me investigate this. I need to start a SIP dialog, if I start it in Kamailio, then I need to work out how all the rest of the stuff falls in place.

Comment: Come over to Skype: ssinyagin